# Camera instead of ethernet cables

Tags: ethernet, layer1, cable

My electricians messed up and installed some sort of camera (or very old cat3?) cables, instead of the requested ethernet cables (see picture). Now I have two of those, running for about 15 meters behind walls and recessed ceilings, making it replacing them very costly.

Is there a way to still use them - grabbing 8 of the cables for gigabit connection and the remaining 4 for a 100mbps connection or some sort of other arrangement?

[image: camera cables]

Comment: That looks like "phone wire", but they're the wrong colors for US standards. It could also be audio cable, or simple signal wire (for thermostats, etc.) It is absolutely not ethernet cable. If your contract specified ethernet cable, you might want to involve lawyers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That three-pair TP(?) cable doesn't look like any cable category, more like a basic signalling cable - a giveaway is an unmarked cable. It might not even have properly twisted pairs.

That's not very likely to reliably run a network connection. A short run could perhaps transport 10BASE-T and possibly even 100BASE-TX. It requires proper pairing in any case, you can't just pair any two wires. But that's not anything a professional network could use. I'm afraid you'll need to replace.

While you're at it you should consider using empty ducting to enable easy cable replacement.

Comment: I see - so I can't just grab 6 cables and call them 3 pairs - they need to be twisted trough all the cable length - so I basically have 2 cables with 6 wires .. not pairs. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Without twisting they'll be useless for networking, even at only 10 Mbit/s. *With* twisting they might be of limited use.

Comment: I'd bet they can run 100 megabit if they are not too long. 15 meters might be pushing it though and it will probably be prone to errors. It's not ideal but it might work. 

Personally, I would try to use the cable as a pull string. It should not be stapled down or secured inside the walls. Carefully attach the correct cable to the one you want to remove and then try to pull the bad one out and see if it moves easily and pulls the new cable in to replace it.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer If that cable's what I suspect then you'd barely get a link up over 15 m. Anyway, there's definitely no professional, on-topic way to operate it as a network link.

Comment: I agree it is no a professional way to do it for sure but you sometimes have to work with what you have, especially when doing the home setup for yourself. If this is a question of a contractor having to deal with what another contractor did then the one who messed up the cabling needs to come back and replace it with cables that are to spec regardless of the cost and time involved.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer, remember that home networking is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: That's fine. It doesn't mean it doesn't exist. ;) It just can't be used for the context of an opening question. The same advice would apply for a small office or even a large office if there is no option available to replace the cable in a timely manner. Give it a shot. Worst case scenario it doesn't work. Then you have to replace it or use WiFi. No harm in trying it before ripping it out. If 10 megabit or 100 megabit works for the use case then it's ok. If more speed is required then replacing the cable is required. Sometimes you have no choice.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments guys, appreciate it!

Comment: @FrameHowitzer *if 10 or 100 megabit work* - you should emphasize that plugging the cable and getting a link light doesn't suffice. I'd seriously recommend rigid, worst-case testing with full-speed, duplex traffic. Anything with a packet error ratio of more than 1:1k (my personal limit is 1:1M) is barely usable - I don't think that 15m link would stay below.

Comment: Yeah very possible it could be terrible. That cable is not even the equivalent of Cat3 but I've seen things work that really should not have. Like coming in to fix an unrelated issue and finding a network running on similar cable with crimp connectors and 66-blocks in the path for a bunch of the connections. Migrated from POTS to Ethernet for convenience/cost reasons and it should not have been usable but the company had been using it for years.

Comment: I tested both cables separately (as patch cables 1-2-3-6) and together (using 4 wires from each cable) - in all cases iperf showed two-way bandwidth at 96 mbps, which is better than expected.